# Is there any single word for "widely used"?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Practical" and "useful" have positive meaning. I am looking for a word with neutral meaning as same as "widely used" that uses neutrally (examples):

- Prescription painkillers are more **widely used** than tobacco, new federal study finds.
- This is a list of British words not **widely used** in the United States.
- Answer to Polystyrene, one of the most **widely used** plastics in the world, has the following formula.

Comment: "Common" or "ubiquitous" come close.  What is wrong with the clear phrase "widely used?" Why do you need a single word?  Because English grammar is flexible, English often doesn't have single words for things that can be easily expressed with phrases.

Comment: I am just curious about it and nothing more.

Comment: Consider "customary".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Prevalent** - [**Dictionary.com**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prevalent)

> widespread; of wide extent or occurrence; in **general use** or **acceptance**.

Eg: These days, laptop computers are prevalent on university campuses.

Answer (score 0):

Prolific: present in large numbers or quantities; plentiful.

> #### [Prolific](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/prolific)
>
> 2. producing constant or successful results

Answer (score -3):

Permit me to offer the word **utilized** in the following sentence:

The students utilized the extensive facilities offered by the university's library and gymnasium.

**Utilize:** (verb) To make use of: turn to practical use or account. (M-W)

Comment: In my answer, I'm aware that the word "utilized" has positive connotations in the context of students and university facilities. I am further aware that the OP has requested a word generating a "neutral"  meaning. I'm unable to reconcile this requirement with my own example. Utilize may also be used in a negative context but without having any positive, neutral or negative meaning as in, for example, "Hitler's Nazi war machine utilized its vast resources in implementing the Final Solution". The word's context is negative but its meaning per se carries no positive, neutral or negative overtones

Comment: 'Utilized' means 'used' not 'widely used'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Oops! I overlooked the OP's position on this. Mea culpa!